# SQL - Returning recent payment date and amount

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created the following query in Oracle to return the most recent payment date and corresponding payment amount from a customer.  It works because I did not include the Amount field.  If I do, it results in multiple rows per company.
Many thanks in advance.

**WORKS (but does not include recent Amount)**

```
SELECT COMPANY_NAME, TERM_CODE, 
MAX(LAST_PYMT) AS LAST_PYMT_REC, 
AR_BALANCE, MAX_CREDIT_AR, OFFSET_BALANCE AS CREDITBAL_W_AP_OFFSETS 
FROM 
(
SELECT COMPANY_NAME,  s2.LAST_PYMT, s2.AMOUNT, 
CURRENT_BALANCE AS AR_BALANCE,
(CURRENT_BALANCE - AP_TOTAL) AS OFFSET_BALANCE,
TERM_CODES.TERM_CODE,
AP_TOTAL,
MAX_CREDIT AS MAX_CREDIT_AR
FROM COMPANIES s1
LEFT OUTER JOIN CTIRELAND.term_codes ON term_codes.tmc_auto_key = s1.tmc_auto_key

inner join
(
  select CR_DETAIL.ENTRY_DATE LAST_PYMT, MAX(CR_DETAIL.CRD_AUTO_KEY),
    CR_DETAIL.AMOUNT, CR_DETAIL.CMP_AUTO_KEY
  from CR_DETAIL
  GROUP BY CR_DETAIL.CRD_AUTO_KEY, CR_DETAIL.CMP_AUTO_KEY, CR_DETAIL.ENTRY_DATE, CR_DETAIL.AMOUNT
) s2
  on s1.CMP_AUTO_KEY = s2.CMP_AUTO_KEY 

  ORDER BY s1.company_name
  )
  GROUP BY COMPANY_NAME, AR_BALANCE, MAX_CREDIT_AR, OFFSET_BALANCE, TERM_CODE
  ORDER BY AR_BALANCE DESC
```

**DOES NOT WORK (returns every Amount made by each company not simply the most recent)**

```
SELECT COMPANY_NAME, TERM_CODE, 
MAX(LAST_PYMT) AS LAST_PYMT_REC, AMOUNT, 
AR_BALANCE, MAX_CREDIT_AR, OFFSET_BALANCE AS CREDITBAL_W_AP_OFFSETS 
FROM 
(
SELECT COMPANY_NAME,  s2.LAST_PYMT, s2.AMOUNT, 
CURRENT_BALANCE AS AR_BALANCE,
(CURRENT_BALANCE - AP_TOTAL) AS OFFSET_BALANCE,
TERM_CODES.TERM_CODE,
AP_TOTAL,
MAX_CREDIT AS MAX_CREDIT_AR
FROM COMPANIES s1
LEFT OUTER JOIN CTIRELAND.term_codes ON term_codes.tmc_auto_key = s1.tmc_auto_key
```

inner join
(
  select CR_DETAIL.ENTRY_DATE LAST_PYMT, MAX(CR_DETAIL.CRD_AUTO_KEY),
    CR_DETAIL.AMOUNT, CR_DETAIL.CMP_AUTO_KEY
  from CR_DETAIL
  GROUP BY CR_DETAIL.CRD_AUTO_KEY, CR_DETAIL.CMP_AUTO_KEY, CR_DETAIL.ENTRY_DATE, CR_DETAIL.AMOUNT
) s2
  on s1.CMP_AUTO_KEY = s2.CMP_AUTO_KEY

ORDER BY s1.company_name
  )
  GROUP BY COMPANY_NAME, AR_BALANCE, MAX_CREDIT_AR, OFFSET_BALANCE, TERM_CODE, **AMOUNT**
  ORDER BY AR_BALANCE DESC

Comment: Does using `sum(AMOUNT)`, instead of `AMOUNT` in the list of selected columns give you what you want?

Comment: @SQLUSER999 Try selecting `MAX(LAST_PYMT) AS LAST_PYMT_REC, AMOUNT` only and check if your getting expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code, hopefully, it solves your requirement. I have added one rank which finds the rank based on last payment date and then I filter your data on rank so you will get all the other columns with rank = "1" from below code.

```
select COMPANY_NAME, TERM_CODE, LAST_PYMT LAST_PYMT_REC, AR_BALANCE, MAX_CREDIT_AR,CREDITBAL_W_AP_OFFSETS
(SELECT  COMPANY_NAME, TERM_CODE, LAST_PYMT LAST_PYMT_REC, AR_BALANCE, MAX_CREDIT_AR, OFFSET_BALANCE AS CREDITBAL_W_AP_OFFSETS,
        rank() over (partition by COMPANY_NAME, AR_BALANCE, MAX_CREDIT_AR, OFFSET_BALANCE, TERM_CODE order by last_pymt desc) rn 
FROM 
    (SELECT COMPANY_NAME,  s2.LAST_PYMT, s2.AMOUNT, CURRENT_BALANCE AS AR_BALANCE, (CURRENT_BALANCE - AP_TOTAL) AS OFFSET_BALANCE,
            TERM_CODES.TERM_CODE,AP_TOTAL,MAX_CREDIT AS MAX_CREDIT_AR
    FROM COMPANIES s1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CTIRELAND.term_codes ON term_codes.tmc_auto_key = s1.tmc_auto_key
    inner join
    (
      select CR_DETAIL.ENTRY_DATE LAST_PYMT, MAX(CR_DETAIL.CRD_AUTO_KEY),
        CR_DETAIL.AMOUNT, CR_DETAIL.CMP_AUTO_KEY
      from CR_DETAIL
      GROUP BY CR_DETAIL.CRD_AUTO_KEY, CR_DETAIL.CMP_AUTO_KEY, CR_DETAIL.ENTRY_DATE, CR_DETAIL.AMOUNT
    ) s2
      on s1.CMP_AUTO_KEY = s2.CMP_AUTO_KEY 
      ORDER BY s1.company_name)
) m
where m.rn = 1
ORDER BY AR_BALANCE DESC;
```

Comment: Vivek, I added "Amount" to your first Select clause and the second Select clause (I think you overlooked these).  Anyway, your code worked perfect to resolve the issue I was having!  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When writing a query as complicated as the one in your question, it is very easy to make a mistake (or two).  As we do not have any real rest data at hand, I'd rather give you a simplified example, which - when you apply the principles presented to your own query - should allow you to find the correct solution yourself.  As @Vivek has suggested, using analytic functions (see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) and [examples](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/analytic-functions)) would be a way to get the resultset you need.

**Test tables**

```
-- helper table
create table T
as
select 
  level as companyid
from dual
connect by level <= 4 ;

-- table used for queries
create table T2
as
select 
  A.companyid
, trunc( dbms_random.value * 1000 ) as amount
, to_date( trunc( dbms_random.value( 2446081, 2458243 ) ), 'J' ) paymentdate
from T A, T B ;
```

**Data**

```
SQL> select * from T2 order by companyid, paymentdate desc ;

COMPANYID  AMOUNT  PAYMENTDATE  
1          766     27-MAY-95 -- <- required 
1          198     12-APR-90    
1          554     05-AUG-89    
1          82      27-FEB-87    
2          195     07-AUG-07 -- <- required      
2          623     07-OCT-03    
2          903     01-NOV-93    
2          519     09-NOV-88    
3          561     27-JUN-97 -- <- required      
3          335     05-SEP-92    
3          327     25-JAN-87    
3          967     04-AUG-85    
4          623     10-APR-17 -- <- required      
4          912     24-FEB-12    
4          385     08-APR-01    
4          708     10-MAR-87 

16 rows selected.
```

The problem is: we want the latest PAYMENTDATE, including its AMOUNT, for each COMPANY - something like the following query, which does NOT work ...

```
select 
  companyid
, max( paymentdate )
, amount               -- cannot get the amount of the last payment(date)
from T2
group by companyid ;
-- ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

If we now add more columns to the GROUP BY clause, we get too many groups (as it were).  This happened to you when you just added to AMOUNT column to the SELECT and GROUP BY clauses.

```
-- if we code
-- ... group by companyid, paymentdate, amount
-- then we get all rows (again) -> no use
select 
  companyid
, max( paymentdate )
, amount              
from T2
group by companyid, paymentdate, amount ;

-- 16 rows selected. (output omitted)
```

Using analytic functions allows us to "group" rows in a different fashion, by writing  (partition by ...).  Notice that the GROUP BY clause is missing from this query.  We get the required PAYMENTDATEs etc.

```
select distinct
  companyid
, max( paymentdate ) over ( partition by companyid ) mostrecentpayment
, first_value( amount ) over ( partition by companyid order by paymentdate desc ) amount
from T2 
order by companyid ;

-- result
COMPANYID  MOSTRECENTPAYMENT  AMOUNT  
1          27-MAY-95          766     
2          07-AUG-07          195     
3          27-JUN-97          561     
4          10-APR-17          623
```

Using @Vivek's approach, for the same test table (resultset the same as above):

```
select 
  companyid
, paymentdate
, amount
from (
  select 
    companyid
  , paymentdate
  , rank() over ( partition by companyid order by paymentdate desc ) rank_
  , amount               
  from T2 
) where rank_ = 1 ;

COMPANYID  PAYMENTDATE  AMOUNT  
1          27-MAY-95    766     
2          07-AUG-07    195     
3          27-JUN-97    561     
4          10-APR-17    623
```

Tested with Oracle 12c.  Note: values in T2 are random!

Comment: Stefan, Thank you so much for your detailed explanation.  Between it and a slight modification to Vivek's response I was able to resolve the issue.  Again, thank you so much for the detailed explanation, I will make use of analytic functions in the future!

Comment: Thank for your feedback! Cheers.